# Would a bluetooth stylus guarantee that I can rest my hand on iPad?

Tags: ipad, bluetooth, stylus

I'm a student who rely on taking note on iPad. It's so convenient. My current stylus doesn't have bluetooth feature so I have to search for app that has hand resting feature. However, I also want to drawing and these apps don't have that. Some drawing apps suggest me which styluses I should use, but I want to use another one.

**Q**: Do I have to stick to the suggestion or is it guarantee that once I connect my stylus to iPad via default bluetooth channel (like connect to the keyboard), I can use whatever app I want, with hand resting feature? During the connection, can I use my finger?

I use iPad 2, but consider to buy a new one.

Comment: I can help you if you are more specific. I need more information from you. Images, exact hardware models and application particulars would be ideal.

Comment: What information do you need? The hardware is iPad 2

Comment: Edit the question to include your iPad 2, the styluses you're looking at, the drawing apps, the handwriting apps. Include anything and everything that might be relevant. The quality of your question and the manner in which it's presented is likely to have a huge impact on the outcome. If the facts are neatly presented and the style is easy to digest etc. chances are; even if nobody here knows the answer (yet), somebody will probably be able to figure something out using the data you present. Does that make sense? Also visual data goes a long way. Imagery of the main items will be most helpful.